# Insert row manually in CellTable in GWT 2.1

Tags: gwt

I have a small problem. In a table with 5 rows I want add a row in between without using setRowData method. Can someone please help me?

Comment: solved By using this   ((TableSectionElement) this.getChildContainer()).deleteRow(rowindex);  when we extend celltable with our class

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but you can try this:
Try setRowCount function . .  first get row count increase it by your number and again set the row count.